# I can't get an e-mail of a specific contact

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my story:
I'm writting a script that permits to see every users in an array of group (I mean, you select 2 group, it show every users in one of these two groups). It also do some other treatment. But it's OK for this part.

Everything seems to work correcly. Except for only one user.
The idea is, I have to get the e-mail of a user, to then compare users'e-mail got in a former group, to see if this user is (or not) already listed ( in order to avoid duplicate).

The user (this one only) won't use my function. I supposed it was a group, but it really is a user.. I'm pretty sure it is an option to select ( or not) in the user's preference, but which one?

PS: here is the error quote

> ```
> TypeError: Fonction getEmail introuvable dans l'objet 
> (TypeError: getEmail function not found in object)
> ```

And here is the code I use in order to get e-mails:

```
for(var i in objuser){

    for(var j in objuser[i])
    {
      objuser[i][j]=objuser[i][j].getEmail();
    }
}
```

Objuser is a list of User Object. First dimension (I) is the group, second dimension (j), is users of the "I" group.

---

PROBLEM NOT SOLVED:

the reason:
I have 2 functions that do treatments. Theses Two function need an array, that another function create (which is long to execute). My code is done in such a way, if i execute consecutively these 2 treatment functions with the same array, the second to be played use an incorrect array.

So i clone it with :

```
var groupsUser2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(groupsUser));
```

but, now that i dont use anymore email adresses ( i mean String), but direct Users (i mean Object), the former code don't clone correctly:

array1 : user's array (Objects)
array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1))

log(array1) :[blabla1@...com,blabla2@...com,blabla3@...com, .....]
log(array2) :[{},{},{}………]

SO.... Here is the new question: Is there a simple way to copy an Object's array ?

Here is the former question: What rights configuration unallow me to use the getEmail() function for a specific contact?

I need an answer just for one of these two questions, and i'll be able to correct my problem. Any idea guys???????

Answer (score 0):

never use "for x in array" its bad use of javascript on an array because the array has the "length" property which is a number and not the object your loop expects.

instead use " for (i=0;...." or forEach.

Comment: True, I may.. But for my information, what is the matter about using it if it works fine ?

Comment: "works fine" really? then why are you posting the question?

Comment: Because it doesn't  work only for 1 user, and this is the getEmail function that cause the problem.

Well, it really work fine with this loop, but maybe there is trouble that i may know before it happens. Adding execution time ? creating bug ? don't know, but i already heard of it , so there is probably a reason.

But again , that's not my point at the moment.

Comment: The code i gave is just to put answerer in condition, even if , i think , my code is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was using getEmail() function in order to compare users got in one group, to others got in another group , so that i can avoid duplicates.
 I was checking with IndexOf() if the user adress were in the array of the other group's users.
I don't know why , but now it works even if i don't get the e-mail of the user. So , the problem that was happening for one user can't happen anymore.

Conclusion: Problem solved. Thx mates

Answer (score -1):

I thought about a solution: `try .. catch`, so that the email which won't be get, will be potentially duplicated because I will not be able to find the user if already displayed or not without his e-mail, but at least the script will not crash.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please edit your question to clarify it instead of posting an answer.